# formatted text not rendering and showing up as code in the view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the [bootstrap-wysihtml5 gem](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails), a WYSIWYG form text editor, for my app. 
When I enter something that looks like this into my text area:

"this is a test to see if **bold** and *italic* are working"

I see this in my view:

```
"this is a test to see if **bold** and *italic* are working"
```

Any html is shown as code instead of getting rendered as formatted text. 
It seems the formatting is getting coded, it's just not rendering correctly. 
What could be causing this?

My code is as below, and closely follows the ReadMe.

**posts/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'wysihtml5' %>

  <%= f.label :photo %>
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
      $(elem).wysihtml5();
    });
  </script>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**posts/_post.html.erb**

```
<div class="photo"><%= image_tag post.photo.url %></div>
<div class="content"><%= post.content %></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in **posts/_post.html.erb**

```
<div class="content"><%= post.content.try(:html_safe) %></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Santosh. I see that `<%= raw post.content %>` works as well. Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: @umezo to understand more about html_safe read this http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to `<div class="content"><%= raw post.content %></div>` and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin. I see that .html_safe works as well. Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: Yes actually. As @Santosh pointed out, html_safe is a better choice because using raw, you might be subjected to scripting attacks. For example, I can post <script>alert('Hi!');</script> and it would execute in `raw`, but not on `html_safe`.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
<%= post.content.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= f.text_area :content,  escape: => false, :class => 'wysihtml5' %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this doesn't seem to work. (At least without changing the view file as suggesed by @Benjamin and @Santosh.)